# Mystery RGB LED ring from defunct Hello Sense device. Trying to make it work

Tags: led-strip, rgb

I can't seem to figure out how to get this LED ring to work.

It's got 4 labeled pads: GND, VCC, VIN, DO.

I tried wiring DO to an Arduino and running FastLed on it but it won't light up. I tried using multiple clockless LED models in the FastLed setup but nothing seemed to work.

- Could this 4th pin be required to make it work?
- Is a resistor required between the DO pin and the Arduino data pin?

[image: Back]
[image: Front]
[image: Front Zoom]

Comment: Looks like a simple 2 layer board. Use a multimeter continuity mode and map it out. Once you know the actual pinout of the leds then you can find what they are easy enough

Comment: It may be 3 layers, a center ground layer? Still you could map it out.

Comment: Is there a resource to help determine which leds they are ?  I have mapped out GND, VCC, DI pin for the leds.

Comment: You should add that to the question. If you have that you have a quarter of the pcb schematic. You should finish it out and use the schematic editor.

Answer (score 2):

Solved !  It turns out these are standard WS2812 leds and the Vin pad is the Data In and DO is dataout.  Connecting the arduino data pint to Vin made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Without the datasheet of the LEDs / Board it will be difficult to give a precise answer.

- VCC -> Probably the power for the logic, most likely 3V3 (Some LEDs has integrated logic).
- Vin -> Probably the power for the LEDs, Voltage / Current ? Unknown, it can be quite high if the LEDs are in series.
- DO -> Probably dataline
- GND -> GND

Probably what to do:

- Apply 3V3 to VCC
- Try your FastLed on DO at 3V3.
- Increase slowly the voltage on Vin

There is good chance you already killed it though.

Comment: Well I do know that the board accepts 5v on the VCC pin when the device is powered up so I'm pretty I didn't kill anything.  The leds do a quick flash when powered is applied.